# Separate a long column of words into more columns inside htmlOutput

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have a shinydashboard which includes a `box` and inside this `box` one long column of words created with `htmlOutput()`. I would like to know if it is possible to separate this long column into 3 columns of text which will be one next to the other inside the `box`.

```
#ui.R
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(
    title = "Enrollment Projections for Fall 2019",
    titleWidth = 500),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
      box(background = "light-blue",          
          htmlOutput("dt1"),
          tags$head(tags$style("#dt1{color: black;
                               font-size: 17px;}")),
          height = 375,width =3))      
    )
#SERVER.R
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  output$dt1<-renderUI({
   str1<-"asddadd"
   str2<-"asddadd"
   str3<-"asddadd"
   str4<-"asddadd"
   str5<-"asddadd"
   str6<-"asddadd"
   str7<-"asddadd"
   str8<-"asddadd"
   str9<-"asddadd"
   str10<-"asddadd"
   str11<-"asddadd"
   str12<-"asddadd"
   str13<-"asddadd"
      HTML(paste(str1, str2,str3,str4,str5,str6,str7,str8,
                 str9,str10,str11,str12,str13, sep = '<br/>')) 
  })
})
```

Comment: why can't you use three box instead?

Comment: there are more things into the box and need to use 1